Anime character that has one black eye with a red pupil, carries a sword, and slices up a bunch of rocks with a girl that has a bunny doll on top
I don't know much about him or her, but I know that they have one black eye with a red pupil and they carry a sword of some sort. There is a scene where he or she slices up a bunch of rocks with a girl on top and the girl has a bunny doll.

The sword-wielding character with the black eyeball and red pupil is Alpha White from the Multiplayer Online Battle Arena game, Extraordinary Ones (2020).

A kendo maiden with an enormous ego. Calmly accepts when people call her "flattie" (yeah right).


The girl with the stuffed bunny sitting on top of one of the 'rocks' is Chang'e. The rocks appear to be blocky cat statues.

Chang'e carries a stuffed bunny, Raby, which becomes alive, grows in physical size and protect her when she's asleep.


The game features anime-style characters and scenes, and so is easily confused with an anime if you've only seen a short clip online.

Extraordinary Ones is a free-to-play mobile Multiplayer Online Battle Arena created by NetEase Games of Onmyōji (2016) fame. Unlike its fellow Chinese MOBAs such as Arena of Valor, it eschews traditional fantasy or quasi-realistic styles for a more anime-influenced aesthetic featuring a multitude of expies of various pop culture icons.

You can view the scene with Alpha White slicing up the cat statues at around the 0:19 mark in the video below.



